# Software to Automate Video Editing

Tags: video, automation, video-editing

I’m working on a project where I need to edit videos regularly, always in the same way. I’m wondering if there is any software out there I could use to automate simple video editing tasks such as stitching multiple videos together, cutting video length, and repositioning them within the frame.

Anything that would allow me to write my own code to interact with an editing program would also work.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, it would save me so much time if it exists.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` toolset may be able to do a lot of what you want...

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of something call RPA (Robotic Process Automation) I am not sure if this is exactly what you want but I will point you to "Kofax Kapow", good luck (It is for business enterprise, but found it rather interesting). This is the link of demo [Automate Business Processes with Kofax Kapow Robotic Process Automation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXaTqretw0A)

Another suggestion if you don't mind to get yourself dirty with coding and programming you can use python and sk-video library [scikit-video video processing in python](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/)

Comment: Thank you, it looks like an RPA May be able to do what I need. I found an open source RPA called Roro that I will be trying as it won’t be just a demo

Comment: Great.Glad to be of help

Comment: If you can code & use Windows, you simply cannot beat AutoIt for automating things